getting minima points of a resampled audio signal

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import resample
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

samplerate, data = wavfile.read("jfk.wav")
data = resample(data, len(data)//4).astype(np.float32)
amin = -32768
amax = 32767
data_norm = 2*(data-amin)/(amax-amin)-1 # (-1, 1)

lows = argrelextrema(data_norm, comparator=np.less)[0]
lows = [index for index in lows if data_norm[index] < 0 ]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=80)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, hspace=0)
axs = gs.subplots()
axs.axhline(y = 0.0, color = 'lightgray', ls='-', lw=1.0) 
axs.plot(data_norm, lw=1)
axs.plot(lows, data_norm[lows], '.', color='red', markersize=8)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close()

How do I get all the points at minima (all the points at the black line)? I have tried concave and convex hulls, and a couple of custom solutions but the nature of audio data is too random that either a point at minima is missed or a point which is not on minima is getting selected. I'm not sure if there is any perfect solution available but even if I get 90% results, I'm OK with it.
NOTE : I'm looking for a generalized solution rather than a parameter or threshold-based method where you have to adjust those values to get the desired result.

we call that "envelope". also look up "alpha shapes", which is an approach to concave hulls. -- there is no parameterless approach because YOU decide which peaks to ignore because they're too close together. your signal gives you a narrow view of all the possible shapes a signal can have.
